# C/C++ code for rearranging .txt file

Tags: c++

Hi i have to make a function in C++ that gets one file as an input and as an output it has another file, that is rearranged in a specific way. In the file there are names of people,names of subject they are teaching, commented lines starting with '#' and also duplicated white spaces. The input file looks like this (before ':' are the names, after it are the subjects):

> john : PA1  ,  PA2,OSY
>    #this is commented line
>    peter: PA1, PA2

And the output in the second file should look like this:

> OSY: john
>   PA1: john, peter
>   PA2: john, peter

As you can see, the function should put one subject on each line (in alphabetical order) and then there should be ':' and after that the names of the people teaching it (also in aplhabetical order). Also all commented lines should be deleted and the same with duplicated white spaces.
I know how to delete duplicated white spaces and commented lines, but I have problem with rearranding the people and subjects. Is there any possible way to do this function without using classes?
I would be very thankful for any help or advices.

```
bool transform  ( const char * inFile,
              const char * outFile )    
{    
  // todo
}
```

Comment: Is is C or C++? Where is the code?

Comment: You don't "rearrange a file", especially in a case like this. You read and parse file to suitable data structures. Then you write data from these data structures to a new file.

Comment: It doesn´t matter if it is in C or C++, and I don´t yet have the "deleting" fuction written, because I am not sure, whether it will be even useful.

Comment: The problem is, that I am quite not sure, how to parse it to suitable data structures.

Comment: Bro, do you even try to write something?

Comment: @user3019115 For this site it matters which language it is. Questions are expected to be quite specific, and leaving language open almost always makes question too broad.

Comment: @user3019115 The question explains everything, but the solution strongly depends on a language, as if it is C++, by using STLs it can be solved in few lines but same isn't true with C. So please specify a language.

Comment: "how to parse it to suitable data structures." - it's a simple mapping. ever heard about maps/dictionaries?

Comment: I didn´t actually. I know C mainly, I am quite new to C++.

Comment: As question is on hold, I'm not able to post an answer. How to post an answer?

Comment: I don´t know, it wants from me to edit the question (which I did) or leave a comment (which I did).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Comment: @user3019115 The question is just too vague. Questions asking for "hints" or other vague things are generally considered off topic here. But you still got plenty of hints to get you started. Don't be discouraged by reception of this question, try to learn from it and ask better next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various **different problems** to solve. You must first identify those individual problems, *then* solve them one by one, and *then* put the pieces together. Many years ago, when I was a student at university, this approach was taught to me as "divide & conquer".

Here are the individual problems I can identify in your question:

1. **Read** a text file's contents into memory, so that you deal with strings and each line is a string.
2. **Parse** a string. Split it into substrings, so that you deal with a collection of strings (tokens). Know when a string starts with a particular character.
3. Create a **data structure** in which a sorted, unique string key relates to a list of (likewise ordered and unique) strings.
4. **Write** a series of strings to a text file.

Each of the sub-problems may well be individual separate questions on Stack Overflow. I'll give you hints for every one of them, so that you can google them or browse the archive for related questions:

1. Reading a text file line by line in order to end up with a series of `std::string` objects is best done with `std::ifstream` and `std::getline`.
2. Getting the first character of a `std::string` is easy: `my_string[0]`, first checking if `!my_string.empty()`. *Splitting* it is more difficult. I would personally use the occasion and get started with the Boost libraries. See the [Boost Tokenizer example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm).
3. The data structure you need is already there - C++ itself provides it as part of the language. The first thing which comes to mind is `std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string> >`.
4. Writing is simpler: use `std::ofstream` and write line by line with `operator<<`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to look it up.

Comment: Great answer! Personal note: a tokenizer might be an overkill for a beginner.

Comment: The problem is, that I can´t actually use Boost Tokenizer, because it is something like homework. It seems that I will have to do the tokenization somehow else.

Comment: @user3019115: There may be other legitimate reasons for not using Boost, of course. But it's just one way of solving the string-splitting problem. If you search the web for "c++ split string", you get almost 3 million results, so you will easily find an approach using only standard C++ features. Hint: you may find `std::string`'s `find` member function useful.

Comment: I think I get it, except one little problem, which is the needed alphabetical order of the names. I would probably parse the lines and pick the subject names and save them into set . That makes them in order. Then I would pick subjects from set one after another and I would write each in the outfile and then find this subject in the infile and look which names are on the same lines as this subject and write then on the same line after the ":" in the outfile. The only problem is, that the names wouldn´t be in alphabetical order.

Comment: I probably need to save the names also  somewhere where they would be put in order and also set somehow which subjects are connected with which names.

Comment: @user3019115: This is the 3rd sub-problem. std::set and std::map both have automatical sorting for strings.

Comment: so if I understand it well, I will have std::map, where type will be std::set.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)  and [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) are your best friends here.